# ASP.NET Core App Having Problems running on an external IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server

Okay so here is my problem. I have a ASP.NET Core Web API that I have to publish onto my company's server. When I run the Application locally, it has no problem starting up. But when I try to publish it to the server, I run into some problems. When I run the app with admin permissions, I get the an error saying that my user cannot access the private key of the certificate and the applicaton crashes.
But when I run the application as Admin, I get a different error. (I think because without admin perms the program cannot access the certificate).
[image]

The program finds the certificate but throws an error saying it cannot configure an endpoint due to no server certificate being specified. When I take a look at the certificate manager, the certificate is also there and has not expired.

I publish the application to the server with the following process.

VS2019 -> Build -> Publish -> Target = Folder -> and then I copy all the dll's/exe's and the config files to a IIS Site.

Comment: The error you posted has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core on IIS, as ASP.NET Core module on IIS uses completely another way to launch your code and does not even touch any certificate (IIS takes care of certificates in that case). So what exactly happened when you access that web app on IIS?

Comment: Hey firstly I'm sorry I didn't really know how to phrase the question. I try to start the app and it crashes giving me the error above

Comment: "I try to start the app and it crashes giving me the error above" is the impossible part. If you indeed follow Microsoft guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio You shouldn't see any error like that because a web app on IIS does not print anything to a visible console.

Comment: TO get the error i just ran the executable inside a cmd window

Comment: Like I said, "i just ran the executable inside a cmd window" is the wrong way to run/test ASP.NET Core (because you are asking Kestrel to execute your code). Kestrel might not be able to locate the certificate and fail. However, IIS doesn't use Kestrel to host ASP.NET Core by default, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0 So you should test IIS hosting and show us whether it works or not.